# MySQL - SELECT * WHERE Dates works, SELECT specific & INNER JOIN WHERE Dates doesn't work

Tags: mysql

This query below gives me the results that I want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   PTAddedApp 
WHERE  PTAddedApp.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2015-01-13'
```

However, this query below gives me 0 results or If I put down WHERE PTAddedApp.date = 0 I get all results with 0000-00-00 as the date value. I have button mashed quite a bit on this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The date column has the date data type.

```
SELECT PTAddedApp.id, 
       PTAddedApp.family_id, 
       PTAddedApp.tid, 
       PTAddedApp.date, 
       PTAddedApp.rate, 
       PT_Tutors.first_name, 
       PT_Tutors.last_name, 
       PT_Family_Info2.billing_name 
FROM   PTAddedApp 
       INNER JOIN PT_Tutors 
               ON PTAddedApp.tid = CONCAT(PT_Tutors.first_name, ' ', 
                                   PT_Tutors.last_name) 
       INNER JOIN PT_Family_Info2 
               ON PTAddedApp.family_id = PT_Family_Info2.id 
WHERE  PTAddedApp.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2015-01-13' 
ORDER  BY PT_Tutors.last_name
```

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for btw? The query returns 0 results because there are no rows in those 3 tables that satisfy all requirements.

Comment: Im looking for the same results that I get from the first query, but I want to join the other tables, and I don't need all from the PTAddedApp table.

Comment: So check your join conditions could be met. We have no idea what data you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to include all of the records that match the where condition from `PTAddedApp` as well as any additional data if found in the joined tables, the following should do the trick!

```
SELECT PTAddedApp.id, 
       PTAddedApp.family_id, 
       PTAddedApp.tid, 
       PTAddedApp.date, 
       PTAddedApp.rate, 
       PT_Tutors.first_name, 
       PT_Tutors.last_name, 
       PT_Family_Info2.billing_name 
FROM   PTAddedApp 
       LEFT JOIN PT_Tutors 
               ON PTAddedApp.tid = CONCAT(PT_Tutors.first_name, ' ', 
                                   PT_Tutors.last_name) 
       LEFT JOIN PT_Family_Info2 
               ON PTAddedApp.family_id = PT_Family_Info2.id 
WHERE  PTAddedApp.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2015-01-13' 
ORDER  BY PT_Tutors.last_name
```

Comment: This gets me the results within the date range, but I get NULL values from the PT_Tutors table. This is definitely a relief!

Comment: Glad to read that it's a relief! Also, do you by any chance know if there's a record which matches the join condition in the PT_Tutors table?

Comment: Thank you for your help Drew. I found the issue with that condition. All is working as I want it to now.

Comment: Welcome Rad! Cool. And glad to read that all is working as you want now! Also, if this answer answered your question or helped you find the answer would most certainly appreciate it if you selected this is as the answer!